# Which Pokémon in Pokémon X/Y are banned in tournaments?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

When playing against buddies during Christmas I want to know which Pokémon are considered "too strong" or "overpowered". In the past generations of Pokémon there have been lists which are banned in tournaments.

I assume the following are:

- Mewtwo
- Xerneas
- Yveltal

But are there others? In that case which might that be?

Comment: It probably varies from tournament to tournement, so you should probably just check with the specific tournament rules. If you are just playing competitively with friends then ban whoever you want..?

Comment: Ditto to JLaBella's comment.  Different tournaments will ban different pokemon, if they even have a ban list set up yet.  There's no 'official' ban list for all tournaments, especially since the game hasn't been out for that long yet.

Comment: Thanks for answers! For the same reason (the game is pretty new) I don't have a perspective on who'm to ban ;) is there any tournaments soon that i can check on?

Comment: I believe all legendary pokemon, all pokemon not native to Kalos, and the speed boost torchic/combusken/blaziken is considered banned

Comment: This is also part of why Smogon provides tiers, consider checking their banlist (It's mostly just mewtwo, xerneas/yvettal,Moody (ability) and blaziken for now I think)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Smogon X/Y Hub page](http://www.smogon.com/xyhub/), *Blaziken* and *Deoxys-N* were quickbanned from the Pokémon X/Y Overused (OU) tier, and there are currently [discussions](http://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/gengarite-tiering-discussion-read-post-383.3493175/) around whether or not to ban Gengarite as well (*Mega Gengar*).

As for the current Smogon ban list, do note that it has been adapted from the Black/White list, and so is subject to change. It's also split into two lists: Pokémon currently available in X/Y, and Pokémon that will become available upon the release of the Pokébank.

Here is the [current Smogon tier page](http://www.smogon.com/xyhub/tiers), listing restrictions on play as well as Pokémon that are banned. If you're planning to hold a tournament (especially after the release of Pokébank), you should consider banning some or all of these Pokémon :

- Mewtwo
- Xerneas
- Yveltal
- Arceus
- Blaziken
- Darkrai
- Deoxys
- Deoxys-A
- Dialga
- Giratina
- Giratina-O
- Groudon
- Ho-Oh
- Kyogre
- Kyurem-W
- Lugia
- Palkia
- Rayquaza
- Reshiram
- Shaymin-S
- Zekrom

Comment: Also note, there's a discrepancy with Deoxys-N. Whilst the Smogon X/Y hub says its banned, the Tiers page does not. [Here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67755325) is a discussion around that fact, it seems De-N isn't as overpowered as originally thought

Comment: It should also be noted that Smogon are mostly bastards and sore losers ;) It doesn't take a genius to figure out you can counter Speed Boost Blaziken with a simple Trick Room, or even Malamar's Topsy-Turvy move. Mega Gengar is super-easy to predict so you can switch to a Sucker Puncher before it Mega Evolves. Really, they're just bound by their own ridiculous rules... I like to just stick to what Nintendo officially says. In this case, no Mewtwo, Xerneas, Yveltal or Zygarde. But if I do go against them, they never last long.